# This website contains all heading words in spans and adds a span for a space, but why?

Tags: html, typography

On this website: https://www.arsenal.com/news/new-fa-youth-cup-kick-time

[image: picture of outcome]

**In the headline New FA Youth Cup Kick Off Time**

If I inspect the element I note that they have contained all words in a `<span>` and added a `<span class="spacer">`.

```
<h1 class="article-card-header__title" title="New FA Youth Cup kick-off time">
  <span class="article-card-header__title-words">
    <span>New<span class="space"> </span></span>
    <span>FA<span class="space"> </span></span
    <span>Youth<span class="space"> </span></span>
    <span>Cup<span class="space"> </span></span>
    <span>kick-off<span class="space"> </span></span>
    <span>time<span class="space"> </span></span>
  </span>
</h1>
```

They also don't specifically select the spacer with any CSS that I can see.  So I'm not sure why it requires a class.

I think this must be something to do with consistency of fonts or spacing.  But I can't really think of a reason why.

Can anyone else think of a good reason as to why someone would do this?

Comment: Please include all relevant code here on Stack Overflow. The site is about asking questions which will stand the test of time; when that site changes their HTML, this question will be close to meaningless. Also, you're asking for speculation, which is pretty close to asking for opinions, which is specifically off-topic on SO.

Comment: I have updated the question.  I know it's close to the mark with regards to speculation, but there is a definitive reason why they took this action.  This isn't going to be for stylistic purposes, or code practice.  So I think it should still stand.

Comment: Note that you can right-click a node and select "Copy outerHTML" so that people can read (and search for) the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the only purpose, but my first thought would be possibly tighter control over line breaks.

You can see in another headline down the page, the classes have been updated to show `row-1` and `row-2`. This particular example doesn't control wrapping any differently than a normal sentence would, but I could see reasons why you might want to force wrap (or no wrap) between different words.

Especially in content/editorial heavy sites, line breaks can be really nuanced and/or problematic.

[image]

Comment: Yes I agree. Widows are a crime in the print world and also the web world but print is a static size so far easier to control. I think this is a good guess.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any logic reasons to do this as no styles are applied to the span elements nor the span.spacer.

In fact you can remove the spans and paste directly the title text and it will look exactly the same.

Comment: Whilst I came to the exact same conclusion, which therefore means way more markup than necessary I can't fathom why anyone would do this unless it's some sort of a CMS, or something.  Even so loads of extra code that someone wrote for no reason.  The only reason I can think of is that the spaces take the place of the natural spacing of the font which may be huge or something like that.  The other explanation is that JS is effecting is not CSS.  For example it may be a good way of avoiding widows by slightly tweaking things one way or the other.

Comment: I have checked the js files, none of them seems to be interacting with the span. They do use Drupal as CMS but I don't why this would be caused by the CMS. Perhaps it's SEO-related?

Comment: If anything I would consider this a negative effect on SEO because it appears like it's not all one sentence, although it's only spans I suppose.  The only thing they are achieving is not letting the font choose its own spacing, so perhaps I have manage to answer my own question.  class="spacer" could be because they want to remember the purpose of that additional empty span and avoid other team members deleting it in the future as it may look like an error.  A comment would be better to achieve this though.

Comment: how did you know it was Drupal?

Comment: I use a browser addon that tells me what technologies every website uses: Wappalyzer. In this case: https://prnt.sc/medmda